# Covering union of intervals

Tags: algorithm, indexing

I am trying to implement a solution to a problem that boils down to interval covering.
by googling I know usually this is solved using a greedy approach, but my own first idea was to use breadth first search. I am starting out assuming the intervals's union is an interval and all intervals are closed. The problem is:

> Given k closed intervals find a subset with as few elements as
>   possible such that every point in an interval from the original collection
>   is in an interval in the found subset.

My idea is to work in a graph where the intervals are the vertices and two vertices
form an undirected edge if the corresponding intervals overlap. In the special case
where the union is an interval I can pick nodes containing the end and start point
having maximal length and then a path between these of minimal length is an optimal solution.
My problem is: How do I build the interval graph efficiently so that I avoid looking at each pair of intervals. I have tried different ways of sorting the intervals but still I seem not get away from quadratic time.

Comment: Did variant with two collections (start/end) with pointers to the same edge didn't brought the right perfomance for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think that in the worst case, you can't get away from quadratic time. That's because the number of edges may be quadratic.

But normal shortest-path algorithm (like Dijkstra) isn't needed here. Start with the first interval (the one with lowest start). Then choose an interval that starts after this one and whose end is the highest. Repeat until you reach end.

Comment: I was hoping I did not have to build complete graph first. If its possible avoid prebuilding, I think breadth first solution is simpler because it is easier to prove correctness.

Comment: To me, the greedy alg's correctness is easy to see.  Take an interval only when forced to.  Conditioned on taking one, get as far as possible.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you could write up the proof ?

Comment: I do not think greedy works, because then either the set of left out intervals or taken intervals would have to define a matroid. I can easily show that the set of left out intervals is not. Greedy probably works to find a good solution but not the optimal one. Maybe someone can work out the competitiveness.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this question because previous entries do not answer it correctly or are incomplete, to the best of my knowledge.

There is an algorithm that runs on O(N log N), where N is the number of closed segments:

1. Order in ascending order the segments by the left end, breaking ties by giving priority to those with the largest right end (breaking ties really does not matter).
2. Apply a greedy strategy from "left to right":

   2.1 while not missing a point, force to choose the segment with largest left end

   2.2 If there is a missing point, there is no solution.

   2.3 Otherwise, go to 2.1

The time complexity of step 1 is O(N log N) and the time complexity of step 2 is O(N). Hence, this greedy algorithm takes O(N log N) time.

Hope this helps!